# Content editor webpart script does not run in IE 11 (runs if developer tools are open)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "/SiteAssets/jquery-2.2.2.min.js">  </script>
 <script type = "text/javascript" >

$(function () {
    console.log('ready');
    MyFunction();
});
```

I am trying to run a simple script in a content editor webpart (SharePoint Server 2010) on a site page in a team site.

The script runs successfully (above) if the developer tools window is open in IE11. If the developer tools are not open the script does not even run. I have tried using alert too instead of console.log but there is no output if developer tools is closed.

Site was added to the compatible view sites before and i tried removing the site and still similar behaviour. I tested the same script in my dev server and the production server with similar output.

Is there a known issue with content editor webpart and IE11 as my googling effort was not able to find.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Rahul

Comment: Your browser is running as an old IE version?

Comment: No, it is running as IE 11. Even in developer tools i have tried from IE 8 to Edge, works completely fine in all versions.

Comment: Can you try running the site with de-activating minimal download strategy in site features?

Comment: Just confirmed again, there is no feature listed under team sites as minimal download strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `console.log('ready')`. This statement throws an error in Internet Explorer if there is no console to write to.

The console is only available when the developer tools are open.

Comment: Thanks, removed every reference to console.log from the script, even the ones which were not being called (error handling functions) and it worked.